# Converting list comprehension into a while loop

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I think this is a really simple question but I get wrong answer.I was doing python programming exercises in an online course and I tried to convert this code to a loop.

```
x = [y for i in range(300)]
```

My answer:

```
counter=0
while counter<300:
    x=y
    counter+=1
```

What is the difference between these two?
How can I convert the first snippet into the second one?

Comment: x needs to be a list, and in your 'translation", it is not a list (furthermore, if you are working with lists, `=` is not what you want, but `append`), and you are simply over-writing x with y. However, you never declared y to anything either, so this is syntactically incorrect as well. Is this the exact code you are working on? Your comprehension is also incorrect, as well.

Comment: `x = list(range(300))` is even better. but this is sooo wrong already: `x = [y for i in range(300)]`

Comment: y is defined. The exercise has the values in its own simulator I think it just gave me the first line and wanted me to convert it into a loop

Comment: another answer that won't please you: `x = [y] * 300`. Way to go: converting very efficient code to unefficient loop + append. Only for educational purposes. otherwise use my snippet.

Comment: `i = 0; x = []; while i < 300: (newline, indent) x.append(y) (newline, indent) i += 1`.

Comment: @Prethia I see your point but not true for immutable types like `int`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried your code with an example dataset it gives the same result but the system does not accept the answer. Do you think it is because of a difference between two while calculating the value? Or is the first code produce something unnecessary that is not needed?

Comment: @Prethia. There is a typo in that code: it should be `x.append(i)`. Or perhaps change all the `i` to `y`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: that's not what the list comp does.

Comment: @Prethia: We have *no information* on the system that tests you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Oops,  yes, you're right - but then in that case the original example code looks incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The output of list comprehension is a `list`, and you haven't created any list in the code, So as we read the list comprehension which goes like `x = [y for i in range(300)]` means that `x` is a list of 300 elements which store the value of the `y` variable. And this can be written in `while` loop as:

```
x = []
counter = 0

y = 10  # Some value defined in your code.
while counter < 300:
    x.append(y)
    counter += 1
```

Comment: I tried your code with an example dataset it gives the same result but the system does not accept the answer. Do you think it is because of a difference between two while calculating the value? Or is the first code produce something unnecessary that is not needed?